# mouseClicked event not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

```
 private JTable getTRent() {
    if (tRent == null) { ...

        tRent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                tDescription.setText(house.getDescripcionMansion(tRent.getSelectedRow()));

                image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(BookWindow.class.getResource(
                        "/images/" + house.getCodeMansion(tRent.getSelectedRow()) + ".png")));

                String childrenAllowed = house.getChildrenAllowed(tRent.getSelectedRow());

                if (childrenAllowed == "N"){
                    txKids.setEditable(false);
                    cbBookHouse.setEnabled(true);
                }

           }
       });
    }
    return tRent;
}
```

The problem that I'm having with the previous code is that any condition, apart from the image, is accomplished, seems to be ignored.

I just checked if the value was read correctly and it is, with a `println` in console, I get a N or Y depending on the row, but if I check that value, nothing happens with the components I want its state to be changed.

Also tried to put those conditions inside the components and the same happens.

The code of the methods `getChildrenAllowed()` for example, is like this

```
      public String getChildrenAllowed(int index) {
      return houseRelation.get(index).getChildren();
  }
```

Comment: everything (from code posted here) inside private JTable getTRent() { is useless, this should be part for add data to TableModel, and really no idea whats your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare strings with `==`, use `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if ("N".equalsIgnoreCase(childrenAllowed))
```

See [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: ListSelectionListener (with test if is row selected) or rowAtPoint

Comment: @mKorbel sorry I'm not getting your point. Are you suggesting the OP use a `ListSelectionListener`? You should post it as an answer. I don't understadn what the OP is asking enough to try and offer that. I just posted what I noticed to be wrong